# Why do I see the wrong static files path in my JS?

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript, css, magento2.4

After installing and deploying the static files, Magento is looking for:

http://127.0.0.1/magento2/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js

instead of:

http://127.0.0.1/magento2/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js

How can I fix it?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because you're using NGINX, so the root folder is the **pub** folder.

Probably the issue is not the file doesn't exist there, but the generation of static files hasn't being performed. Try these commands below to set the store in the developer mode and to generate all the static files.

```
alias mage="php -d bin/magento" && \
mage deploy:mode:set developer && \
mage setup:upgrade && \
mage cache:flush && \
mage indexer:reindex && \
mage setup:static-content:deploy -f && \
mage setup:di:compile
```